# Spring Boot Test - I do not want to load all @Configuration classes for a particular test

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a half-dozen classes in an application annotated with `@Configuration` and am writing unit tests.

I have one `@Configuration` class that sets up Quartz, and one that deals with setting up Camel.

In my Camel unit test, I only want to load the `@Configuration` class that sets up Camel, because it does not care about Quartz (and vice-versa).

How do I tell my Spring Boot test to only bootstrap certain configuration-annotated classes?  `@TestConfiguration` does not do that...

```
@Configuration
public class QuartzConfig {
    ...
}

@Configuration
public class CamelConfig {
    ...
}

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@SOME ANNOTATION THAT SAYS ONLY LOAD CamelConfig.class???????
public class CamelOnlyTest {
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By using [the `classes` parameter of `@SpringBootTest`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/context/SpringBootTest.html#classes--), you can specify which classes to use for configuration.

From the docs:

> public abstract Class[] classes
>
> The annotated classes to use for loading an ApplicationContext.

Comment: Thanks!  I used `@ContextConfiguration(classes={CamelContextLoader.class})` instead but that method would work too!